# Apache Pig performance optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I have written few Pig Scripts which i have included in one Pig Master Script using RUN. Reason behind including all scripts in Pig Master Script is that we are doing one final left join on all variables (variables -> schema projected in each script) to create one big file.

Problem: Execution is taking very long time to finish. currently its taking more than 27 mins and expected time is 5 - 6 mins.

Cluster Information: its 10 node cluster (xlarge) on Amazon.
Is there any way to acheive  this.

Comment: the problem can be anywhere - data, cluster configuration, cluster size, script... please share more information.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help :

```
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/perf.html
```

Or this :

```
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch08.html
```

Comment: this link takes you nowhere